# how can i add items which are checked to arraylist  in Gridview c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to keep some data which is checkhed  in array list. I added checkbox to gridview and when i checked  one of items. click event of checkbox runs for all so for example, I have two data when i click the any checkbox  it  runs 4 times, so it works for each one however, I want that only the item of one checkbox which is checked or unchecked is added to list.  Is there solution or another solution

```
     // checkbox click event 
    protected void SelectedFriends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        bool isflag=false;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            // Access the CheckBox
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FriendSelector");

            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {




                string friendname = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (friendname.Equals(list[i].ToString()))
                    {
                        isflag = true;
                    }
                }
                // if it is added previously  don't add to list
                if(!isflag)
                {
                    list.Add(friendname);
                }

            }
            else
            {

                string friendname = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (friendname.Equals(list[i].ToString()))
                    {
                        isflag = true;
                    }
                }
                // if it is not checked and it is in list delete it from list
                if(isflag)
                {

                    list.Remove(friendname);
                }

            }
        }


    }






    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Bold="True" 
            Width="157px">
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="FriendSelector" 
                  oncheckedchanged="SelectedFriends_Click" AutoPostBack="True">

            </asp:CheckBox>

            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="F_Name" HeaderText="Friend Name" 
                    SortExpression="F_Name" />
            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
protected void SelectedFriends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        list.Clear();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            // Access the CheckBox
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FriendSelector");

            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {

                string friendname = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                list.Add(friendname);

            }
         }


    }
```

Comment: it seems that data is added successfully but list.Count() is equal 0 I dont understand the reason when i click a buttoon            protected void      Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (list.Count == 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "There is no selected friend";
            }
            else
            {
               
                DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
                Boolean result = db.ShareRSS(selectedId,username,list);
            }

        }

Comment: If you declare a variable outside all the functions ('global') its state will not be maintained after the postback. So you need to use Session. Add list to session in the above function after adding all the items. Then where you check the list, take it from session.

Comment: Then you can mark it as answer so that it will help others too.